# jQuery debugging the .one method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how code is setting a certain data attribute of an image. I know where it is being set but fully understand how.

```
 var img = $("<img />").one('load', function () {
        if ($.browser.version < 9 && $.browser.msie) {
            var _WidthHeightWidth = Utilities.getNatural(this);
            if (typeof _WidthHeightWidth.width == "undefined" || _WidthHeightWidth.width == 0) {
                $(img).attr("data-type", "error");
            } else {
                $(img).attr("data-type", "success");
                $(img).attr("width", _WidthHeightWidth.width);
                $(img).attr("height", _WidthHeightWidth.height);
            }
            if (!$(img).data("one")) {
                $(img).attr("data-one", true);
                fn ? fn(img) : null;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                $(img).attr("data-type", "error");
            } else {
                $(img).attr("data-type", "success");
                $(img).attr("width", this.naturalWidth);
                $(img).attr("height", this.naturalHeight);
        }
            if (!$(img).data("one")) {
                $(img).attr("data-one", true);
                fn ? fn(img) : null;
        }

        }
            //var _WidthHeightWidth = Utilities.getNatural(this);

        }).one("error", function () {

            $(img).attr("data-type", "error");
            if (!$(img).data("one")) {
                $(img).attr("data-one", true);
                fn ? fn(img) : null;
}
```

breakpoints are entering the method `}).one("error", function () {` but I don't quite understand why, This image was originally a `.tif` that was renamed to `.jpg`, is that reklevant. The file downloads from the server fine using an asset handler.

Comment: Just because you renamed the extension, does not mean the file type changed. It's probably still serving a `tiff` mime type which most browsers cannot open. Also, `$.browser` is deprecated and I believe removed as of ***1.9***.

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure as Chrome downloads the image perfectly and it looks fine. Although the console does say there is a mime type error so the javascript must see an error that the browser ignores